# Is it wrong to just say that things continue at constant velocity unless acted upon, as velocity is only relative?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, inertial-frames, velocity, relative-motion

Like when saying that people mistakenly thought things automatically slowed down after being thrown etc (accelerated), because that's just due to all the air or surface friction or gravity. Do you have to specify the reference frame? And no reference frame is more true?

Comment: The statement that "_things continue at constant velocity unless acted upon_" is wrong if stated with respect to an accelerated reference frame. I think your thinking is restricted to inertial reference frames only when in fact there are many more kinds of reference frames.

Comment: My thinking is not restricted to inertial reference frames thanks

Comment: Well, inertia only makes things "continue at constant velocity" with respect to inertial reference frames, hence the name.

Comment: I knew it wouldn't look the same from an accelerating reference frame, hence I'm not that stupid.

Comment: @CarlBerger Inertia isn't the cause, it's property. It doesn't cause things to move at constant velocity without force but this is the name of the property of objects that they move at constant velocity in absence of force.

Comment: If you deny it then how exactly does inertia does that? If you say that nobody knows, then what's the point of saying that?

Comment: @Aday I never meant any offence. I didn't specifically talk about accelerating reference frames - you had commented "not restricted to inertial reference frames" - and i was referring to that.

Comment: @Osmium I never dived into the cause-and-effect discussion. Nevertheless the statement in question is only true for inertial reference frames.

Comment: @CarlBerger thx for clarifying. My question was indeed meant to be about inertial reference frames.

Answer (score 8):

Not wrong. Newton laws was formulated for absolute space and inertial reference frames. All inertial reference frames are equal, so as long as you will analyze law of inertia from any inertial reference frame - it will hold, because it's just a matter of Galilean transformation $u'=u+v$. But, of course if you are moving for example in accelerating rocket, then law of inertia for some object thrown out of rocket window will not hold anymore, and you will need to account for your rocket acceleration- adding pseudo force to an object.

If you like, for the sake of peace, you can look around for an absolute space (absolute reference frame) postulated as axiom in Newton theory,- it can be for example a cosmic microwave background, or take a reference most distant galaxy or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

If you are riding in a car and look out of the window, are the trees moving (or is the car moving and the trees are still)?

If you accelerate in that car while looking out of the window, do the trees accelerate (or are they still not moving and the car is accelerating)?

If you said that the car is accelerating and the trees are not, you are using a(n approximately) inertial reference frame where things really do continue at a constant velocity unless acted upon.

If you said that the trees are accelerating, then you are using a non-inertial reference frame where trees are able to accelerate without any force being applied to them.

The default for most people is to use an inertial reference frame, so it's easy to gloss over the fact that that's actually an assumption.

Comment: Why would the car accelerating and the trees not moving be an APPROXIMATELY inertial reference frame? I'm guessing it might have something to do with the universe's expansion accelerating, which means everything is under acceleration, but I'm not sure at all.

Comment: @Blueriver Gravity. In this case it's close enough for our purposes because the car and the tree are implied as being near to each other so they share very nearly the same acceleration from Earth, sun, etc., etc., etc. But if your car happens to be at one of the poles and the tree is at the equator, then you see the tree move differently from the car because the tree actually does have a force being applied to it that's not being applied to the car.

Comment: @Blueriver Or, and this is a fun one, say you have a tree at the equator and an airplane that starts above the tree and travels at ~460m/s in the direction directly opposite to the Earth's rotation. Start at noon so that the sun is directly overhead for easy visibility. Now sketch out the motion of these relative to each other: sun, Earth center of mass, tree, you in your airplane.

Comment: It makes sense to me that at different distances from the Earth's center (and with a universe with just a spherical and uniform Earth) the pull from gravity is different. However, two objects at rest (on the floor of different apartments in the same building) with height h1 = 0m and h2 = 10m are affected (very slightly) differently by Earth's gravity, but their acceleration is still 0, so (I THINK!) each object would have its own (perfectly, not approximately) inertial reference frame. The car and the trees also have a vertical acceleration of 0. How does height impact then?

Comment: Same goes for the Sun's gravity. The car and the trees are not accelerating towards the Sun at all (because there are other forces than the Sun's gravity). So I understand how two asteroids sitting next to each other would be APPROXIMATELY inertial reference frames, but not why these objects, which are not changing their velocities (i.e. not accelerating) would not be perfectly inertial reference frames. I'm sure there's something I'm missing, or some assumption I'm making that is simply not true, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: I feel bad because the "approximately" part was very obviously not the core point of your answer, which I upvoted and think is very good, yet I'm kind of making a big fuzz about this. For some reason it really stood out to me, but feel free to continue this in chat or not at all if you prefer. I could always straight up ask a Question here.

Comment: @Blueriver https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134570/discussion-on-inertial-frames-of-reference No worries, this stuff can be really counter intuitive. "How can we talk about logic in a world where people talk about the sun setting instead of the horizon rising?"

Answer (score 3):

> Do you have to specify the reference frame?

Yes, it is necessary. Velocity indeed has a meaning only as a relative quantity. However, in any non-inertial system, free bodies, i.e., bodies with no action by other bodies, do not move at constant velocity.

Things can be seen in the following way: the acceleration of a body, in general, depends on the position and velocities of other bodies **and** on the reference frame. However, there is a particular class of reference frames, the inertial frames, characterized by the property that a test particle moves with constant velocity in the absence of other bodies or far enough from them. In a non-inertial system, this is not true anymore.

Notice that the inertial reference systems are not *more true* than others. They are *simpler* because accelerations are *only* due to the action of other bodies.

Comment: I thought acceleration wasn't dependent on other bodies and frames, but a real force accelerating something. I must totally misunderstand something.

Comment: @Aday The concept of force had a complex history. The best way to think it is as a function that tells us what is the acceleration of the body. It turns out, and it is the content of the laws of motion, that that function depends on the body itself through the mass of the body. After dividing the force by the mass, we have the acceleration of the body, and the resulting acceleration depends, in general, on the dynamical coordinates of other bodies and on the reference frame chosen for describing the motion.

Answer (score 2):

In Newtonian terminology we say that objects will continue at constant speed in a fixed direction if they are not subjected to any force- that is what Newton's first law tells us. (You need to bear in mind, however, that Newton's laws assume that gravity is a force. In General Relativity, gravity is not considered a force but an effect due to the curvature of spacetime, so in the context of GR we would phrase things differently.)

To quantify the speed and direction, you need to specify some frame of reference.

As far as we know, there is no 'absolute' frame of reference.

Physicists usually pick frames of reference that simplify the particular calculations they need to perform. For example, when studying the relative movement of two objects in Special Relativity we usually pick a frame in which one object is stationary and the x-axis is aligned along the direction of the relative motion of the two objects. We could pick any other reference frame, but that would make the calculations more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you have to specify the reference frame? And no reference frame is more true?

Velocity is not an absolute variable, it is frame dependent. The second question I do not understand, please clarify.

> Is it wrong to just say that things continue at constant velocity unless acted upon, as velocity is only relative?

It is not wrong - this is exactly what the *first Newton's law of motion* states: if the net force on an object is zero, the object will be in *equilibrium*. The equilibrium means that object is moving at constant velocity, which can be zero but does not have to!

Let’s say that the velocity measured from the ground (Earth) is zero. In some other reference frame it might not be zero, but it is constant if this reference frame is also inertial, i.e. if it does not accelerate. The first Newton’s law is valid in both frames.

Please note that the ground (Earth) is *not true inertial reference frame*, but it is considered as one within some margin of error. The Earth rotates around its axis and orbits around the Sun, which gives it (very small) acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

This will repeat others' ideas, but introduce some hopefully helpful terminology. The Aristotelian idea that with no force velocity isn't **conserved** shouldn't be conflated with the Newtonian idea it will be conserved, but *qua* Galileo not **invariant**. Whereas just about any reference frame change will change quantities that aren't invariant, without a force the velocity is conserved as long as we only work with, and therefore only change between, **inertial** reference frames.

Comment: Yes I read through that history to get to this. So I need to stop thinking of conservation of velocity? Instead think that while the number/direction can vary, per other inertial reference frame, it will be one constant value before it accelerated and one constant value after it was accelerated?